# How should I use a plumber's snake?

Tags: plumbing, repair

How should I use a plumber's snake if my kitchen sink drain got clogged? Are there any suggestions on when this device is applicable and how to use it?

Comment: Is it just the sink that's blocked or are other fixtures gurgling/bubbling, toilet water going down too far after a flush or not residing quickly?

Comment: @UNECS, the sink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lowe's](http://www.lowes.com/cd_Clear+Clogged+Drains_587687001_) has a nice overview, but here's a quick summation: First, check the sink trap to see if the clog is there. Most kitchen sinks have a "clean-out plug" in the u-bend pipe attached to the drain under the sink - this pipe is called the "trap." It should have a "cap" screwed into it, called a clean-out plug, with a square knob on it - this knob is where you put a pipe wrench to loosen the plug and remove it. Be sure to have a good size basin, bucket or large mixing bowl underneath to catch anything coming out of it! If you don't see the clog, feed the snake into the drain from the plug, until you feel the obstruction... if you don't run into the clog, try feeding the snake up the other way, it could be between the sink and the trap. Rotate the snake's auger while keeping up a gentle forward pressure, and this will break up the clog. When you pull out the snake, it will probably have some nasty, dripping gunk on the auger, so keep that basin and some paper towels handy!